# Moving Horses behind closed doors

Tags: probability

Here's a question I've been stuck on for a while now: A stable consisting a row of $8$ stalls houses $1-8$ horses. You may check whether a horse is in a stall by opening it, but must close it immediately after checking. Every time you close a stall door, all the horses move to either the left or right stall independently. A stall can hold any number of horses, but initially each contains no more than 1 horse. How many times must you open doors to see each horse at least once?

Edit: Assume that when you open a door, you can see the number of horses behind the door and that you can recognize a horse that you've already seen before.

So my main thought process so far has to define a function $f(x)$ that asks "given that we have seen $x$ horses so far, how many more doors to we need to open to see a new horse." Then $\sum_{i=1}^7 f(i)$ is the desired answer. But the fact that the possible positions of each horse depends on where they started out makes this function harder to compute.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: math.stackexchange.com/tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: What information do you get by opening a door and seeing the horse or horses behind it?  The number of horses?  Can you tell whether a horse is a new horse you haven’t seen before?  Can you recognize a horse that you *have* seen before?  (Not sure if these affect the answer or not, but it seems like they might affect your strategy.)

Comment: The answer will depend on whether there is stall wraparound, the stalls you open and the number/distribution of horses. None of these have been specified.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I've edited the question to address your questions.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel There is no wraparound in that the horses on the ends have only one choice (which is specified in the question). The "stalls we open" is part of the strategy that the question wants us to come up with. The number/distribution of the horses has been specified — there are 8 horses, one in each stall.

Comment: This is less of a calculation problem and more of a tricky logic puzzle. Consider just one of the horses. Can he avoid you forever, or is there some sequence of stalls you can look at that guarantees you'll catch him? (There is, but it's not obvious.)

Comment: @Karl Well since the movements are random, we know that every horse ultimately goes to the left most stall (Murphy's law). So one strategy is to just keep opening the leftmost stall over and over. But I need a strategy that is also optimal, which is why it's tricky.

Comment: @KidBrains Do the horses move left with $50\%$ probability? The strategy of repeatedly checking the first door doesn’t work if a horse moves left and right forever, for example.

Comment: @Tavish yes, you're right. The probability of moving left/right is not necessarily 0.5 so my strategy was incorrect.

Comment: Imagine the horse knows which doors you're going to open. Can he avoid you forever? If so, then a very lucky randomly-moving horse can also avoid you for any finite number of days. So you need a strategy that catches the smart horse.

Comment: @Karl What is the sequence of stalls, out of $n$, you can look at that guarantees you'll catch a single horse in the worst case?  This, multiplied by the number of horses, is certainly an upper bound on OP's question (just repeat the strategy for each horse).  As you say, "probability" is a red herring; this is purely a logic problem.

Comment: @mjqxxxx $1,2,...,n,n,...,2,1$ works. The forward pass catches all horses that start on an odd-numbered stall and the backward pass catches the others. (The direction doesn't really matter, but this sequence was the easiest to describe, as hitting $n$ twice flips the parity.) You don't have to repeat this for each horse.

Comment: A fun generalization is: characterize the graphs G for which if the stalls are the vertices of G (and the horse moves to an adjacent vertex each night), we have a winning strategy.

Comment: Yes, I’ve seen that generalization: https://projecteuler.net/problem=690

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Consider a simplification, reducing the number of horses. For example if there are 2 stall houses, let's name them A or B. We want to check if there is a horse.

Let's focus on the case we only have one horse, when there are two or no one is analogous to this case.

1. Check stall house A. If there is a horse, we won.
2. In case we haven't found the horse yet, since the horse must've moved right or left, the only possibility is the horse is in stall house A (since it was in stall  house B). Check stall house A, we found the horse!

The most important fact is that horses dont stay in one stall house, and we can generalize the argument to a higher number of horses.

Comment: In the case where we have $n$ horses and $n$ stables, for $n=1, 2, 3$ it seems as though we only need to open $n$ stalls. I'm finding it difficult to generalize this to any larger $n,$ though, simply because the variance increases.

Comment: @KidBrains I dont think it's possible to give a 'minimal' number of stalls to open that works every time, but with this algorithm you can track the stalls and certainly finish in finite some.